# Memory Management with Gesture Recognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

A lot of my memory leaks are coming from this code that recognizes swipes. What am I doing wrong?  The first line is something that I think is leaking (using Instruments). It's being shown as the responsible caller for a lot of the errors
This is in ViewDidLoad:

```
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
    [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeRight.delegate = self;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
    [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeft.delegate = self;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}
```

One more question, what could cause a zombie here? Should I be autoreleasing?

```
    AViewController *a = [[AViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:a animated:YES];

a.title =@"A View";
[a release];
```

Update 3: I ran instruments to look for bad allocations and with some intensive use I get a zombie here: 
Error Message: `An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0xf583270.`
In instruments here's what I'm seeing. Instruments highlights this line and has 100% next to it.

```
AViewController *a = [[AViewController alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory management in object-c is something that takes a bit of getting used too for sure. I personally let the operating handle everything for me. What this means is everytime I alloc something, I just give it an autorelease. The OS will handle the release for me when it needs to. The only time this is a problem is when you reuse an object in the same scope, the OS will send it too many releases and free the memory before you want it too. Here is an example

```
//This code will result in a memory crash
CustomObject *coolThing = [[[CustomObject alloc] init] autorelease];
[coolThing setAwesomeLevel:10];
[array addObject:coolThing];

[coolThing setAwesomeLevel:7];
[array2 addObject:coolThing];
```

Instead you would use

```
//Working code
CustomObject *coolThing = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
[coolThing setAwesomeLevel:10];
[array addObject:coolThing];

[coolThing setAwesomeLevel:7];
[array2 addObject:coolThing];

[coolThing release];
```

Now, to use autoreleases with your code, all you would do is add them to the allocs. This is why your code is leaking. When you add it to the webView object, it is increasing its retain account. And when you leave that scope, it has a retain account of 2, but you only ever send it one release (its retain would remain at 1, and never release the memory).

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)] autorelease];
[(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
swipeRight.delegate = self;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)] autorelease];
[(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft.delegate = self;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

if you do not want to use autorelease like this, you need to simply add some releases after you add the gestures to the webView.

```
[swipeRight release];
[swipeLeft release]
```

Comment: Great explanation! I'm still getting used to memory management and this was helpful!

Comment: btw, I added an extra bit of code to the question. Would that be a situation where I would want to use autorelease? If we rapidly switch back and forth, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: the code you added is correct. Adding an autorelease and removing the end release will result in the same code. This would not be the problem I mentioned above as you are not changing the object in the same scope. The problem I described above is very rare and I make sure to mention it any time I mention the autorelease capabilities.

Comment: I would read apple's memory management guide. Autoreleasing everything isn't really the best way to learn/understand it. and once you get the concept of ownership under control its not really a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. I wasn't planning on autoreleasing everything, but for anyone reading along the link is here:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23/

Comment: @Jesse Naugher: You misunderstand my post. I do not say to learn via autoreleasing or that it is the "best" way to accomplish memory controlling. It is however the easiest. Especially when you are not sure if certain functions retain. I do agree that you should have a firm grasp on memory ownership concepts as an objective-c programmer. It is definitely a different beast when you come from a background where it does everything for you (ex: Java)

Comment: @coldlogic: i agree. i was just trying to add to the OP for best practice purposes. your post is quite useful.

Comment: I've updated the post, but I'm having pretty big issues with zombies on this call. What's happening?

Comment: No matter what I do, I still get a crash (after intensive use, probably not real world equivalent) but no matter what I do, it shows that a zombie was messaged. I've been trying to figure it out, but it seems to escape explanation. The line seems to be written correctly, but it still occasionally can give me a zombies messaged, if you rapidly switch views.

Answer (score 4):

you are alloc/initializing a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` (which makes it your job to release it) and not releasing it in your top piece of code, twice. you need to add a `[swipeRight release];` and a `[swipeLeft release];` after you have added those to your webview.

Comment: seems to have addressed the Gesture Recognizer leaks for the most part. :)

Comment: One more question though, I added something to the question (code doesn't format in comments)

Comment: if you don't use `a` again after its released there shouldn't be a zombie problem..but you should set the title before you push it onto the navigationController stack..that might cause some kind of issue.

Comment: I see. Should I be doing :     [AViewController release]; and 
    [aview release]; or just the second one

Comment: since the instance of the object is called `a` thats what you release. so your release call there is fine (as long as you don't use `a` after it that you don't show in the post). I would definitely move the `a.title` line to above the `pushViewController:` line though.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the gesture to your views call a `release`  method on it, because the gesture is **retained** by the **views** in which you add.

Like below

```
 [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];  
    [swipeRight release];
```

And

```
 [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];  
    [swipeLeft release];
```

Comment: right, I think that should solve it. I don't know how that got by me. I'm testing that now :)